# Issues with resetting state stored in local storage, using redux-storage

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-storage

I'm using react-storage in an app to persist my state in my local storage. In an attempt to clear the state, I do this:

```
import createEngine from 'redux-storage-engine-localstorage'
const engine = createEngine('my-save-key');

...

engine.save({})
.then( () => {
  dispatch({type: 'SOME_ACTION'})
})
...
```

`engine.save({})` should theoretically save the state in my local storage to an empty object. After this is done, I expect the next dispatched action's previous state to be that empty object. However, somehow the action dispatched in the `.then` still has reference to the old state, and it's as if the state was never reset.

Also, I've been experimenting with localStorage.clear() to reset the state, but I encounter the same problem. Any ideas on what might be wrong, and how I might fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's doesn't look like Redux uses the state stored in localstorage unless it's told to do so with `engine.load()`. And that's a good thing. If using localstorage meant that Redux shouldn't keep its own state in memory, but always read from localstorage, that would be horrible for performance. `engine.save()` doesn't seem to do anything with the actual redux state, it just sets the localstorage value to something that you may load later, e.g. the next time you start the application.

`engine.load()` would typically be something you use to get the initial state of your application, and then use `engine.save()` any time you want to take a snapshot of the current state that can be reproduced at a later point. The source code for `save()` and `load()` should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
export default (key) => ({
    load() {
        let jsonState;

        try {
            jsonState = localStorage.getItem(key);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err.message);
        }

        return Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(jsonState) || {});
    },

    save(state) {
        const jsonState = JSON.stringify(state);

        try {
            localStorage.setItem(key, jsonState);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err.message);
        }

        return Promise.resolve();
    }
});
```